# Calculating Probabilities in Naive Bayes Classification

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, probability, naivebayes

I have a data set consisting of both categorical and continuous attributes. I want to apply Naive Bayes classification method to classify the data.

How to calculate probabilities for both of these types?

Should I use count method for calculating on categorical data and assume some distribution and calculating from that on continuous data ?

Answer (score 1):

As Naive Bayes assumes independence of each feature obervation given a class label you have

```
P(cat1, con1|y) =  P(cat1|y)P(con1|y)
```

where `cat1` is some categorical variable and `con1` is continuous, you model each of these probabilities completely independently. And as you suggested, for categorical you can use simple empirical estimator (however remember about some smoothing techniques so you do not get 0 probabilities) and for continuous you need some more sophisticated estimator (such as MLE using fixed distributions family - for example gaussians; or something more complex - as any probabilistic classifier/model)